Why is pandas str functions slower than apply?
I'm processing a large dataset, particularly these two columns:



Genotype
Iteration




10010110011011101101011000010011111011111000000111001001101111111101101111001011
0


00011100001011010000000110010010100101101011001010101110110111000101000110000000
0


00100100100100101000100101100110100101110000100111000000011001011001101111000011
0


10001010101100000101110001011111000110101100101010111100110011011101010011111110
0


11010101010010001110100110110001001010101001111000111011110110101101010100011110
0



I want to create a new column that tells me how many 1s the column Genotype has.
I've tried two methods:

With built-in str module

%%timeit
total_df['Count_1'] = total_df['Genotype'].str.count('1')
10.9 s ± 183 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


With apply():

%%timeit
total_df['Count_1'] = total_df['Genotype'].apply(lambda x: x.count('1'))
2.63 s ± 13.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

A significant improvement is obtained using the second approach but, as far as I knew, the apply() method was slower than using pandas built-in methods.
What am I missing?
I don't know if this is useful but pd.__version__ is 2.0.3.

You aren't missing anything. It's always been this way with string operations in pandas. It runs in python speed but with added overhead

String functions are not vectorized.

Related: pandas#35864 - Vectorized string operations are slower than for-loops

this isn't surprising with the object dtype and standard pandas, but of curiosity, try converting the string columns to dtype="string[pyarrow]" and try again with the .str accessors

If you stick to pandas on cpu, you'll find that list comprehension is actually faster than apply as well. However, if you install cudf, a gpu library, and load its extension, pandas' .str becomes much faster than apply or comprehension.

@juanpa.arrivillaga It doesn't work or I don't know how to do it.

The answer is that the str operations are not vectorize as @mozway and @roganjosh mentioned.
